# Autopopulate a RANGE of Cells from one sheet (tab) to another in a single workbook

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

All I want to do is have cells in one sheet (tab) in a workbook auto-populate with data and formatting of a different sheet (tab) in the same workbook. I know how to do this one cell at a time, BUT is there a way to do this so that I can select a range of cells all at once? 
Example:

- `Tab A, Range A3:D36` would automatically populate with data from 
  `Tab D, Range A2:D35`.

Answer (score 1):

- you can use either: **`={'Tab D'!A2:D35}`**
- or even: **`=QUERY('Tab D'!A2:D35, , 0)`**